# Jquery comparing strings not working in POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-comparison

I have a jquery post code that can have two different reactions based on the response.  if the response is `a` then i would like to `alert()` if it is not `a` then i would like to update a div (ratebox).  However, one of the lines (below) isn't working. It appends the letter `a` onto the ratebox when it should bring up the alert.  I checked that answerrating.php does produce the letter a.

JQUERY:

```
$.post('../answerrating.php' , {answer_id: answer_id , direction: 2} , function(response){
        if (response == 'a'){  //this line doenst work
            alert("error");
        }
        else {
            ratebox.text(response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: and how does server side response look like?

Comment: @Nazariy as stated in the question it does produce the letter a as expected

Comment: Try `data.response` instead of `response`.

Comment: @dyelawn should i change this inside the function and the comparasin or just one of them?

Comment: your function should read `function(data)` and your if statement should read `if(data.response == 'a')`

Comment: If you using Firebug add following code before if statement `console.log(typeof response, response);`

Comment: @dyelawn i tried it and it didnt work

Comment: I'm afraid it's difficult to provide proper assistance without more information. Please do try Nazariy's suggestion of using Firebug, or if you're using Chrome or Safari, use its built-in web inspector. My suggestion will only work if you've named the "response" in the data coming back from the server. If you're not getting anything else from your server side script other than that string, then replace all of your `response` variables with `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you get some whitespaces in the response, try using `jQuery.trim()`:

```
if ($.trim(response) == 'a'){  //this line doenst work
   alert("error");
}
```

You could also use `firebug` to check so that your response don't include any html.

If you are getting something other than plain text from the server try setting the `dataType` in your call:

```
$.post('../answerrating.php',
  {
    answer_id: answer_id, 
    direction: 2
  }, 
  function (response) {
    //this line doenst work
    if (response == 'a') {
      alert("error");
    } else {
      ratebox.text(response);
    }
  },
  dataType: 'text'
);
```